New to VBA, code is taking 5- 10 minutes on spreadsheet with 3000 lines. Any suggestions where the bottle neck is, or a better approach?
Sub UpdateColumnsBasedOnBR()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim valuesBR As Variant
    Dim valuesL As Variant
    Dim valuesM As Variant
    Dim valuesN As Variant
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM") ' Change "BOM" to your sheet name
    
    ' Disable screen updating and calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column BR
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "BR").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Read data into arrays
    valuesBR = ws.Range("BR2:BR" & lastRow).Value
    valuesL = ws.Range("L2:L" & lastRow).Value
    valuesM = ws.Range("M2:M" & lastRow).Value
    valuesN = ws.Range("N2:N" & lastRow).Value
    
    ' Loop through each row in column BR
    For i = 1 To UBound(valuesBR, 1) ' Arrays are 1-based
        Select Case valuesBR(i, 1)
            Case "SAME"
                ' Carry over values
                ws.Cells(i + 1, "CB").Value = valuesL(i, 1)
                ws.Cells(i + 1, "CC").Value = valuesM(i, 1)
                ws.Cells(i + 1, "CD").Value = valuesN(i, 1)
            Case "REPLACE", "ADD"
                ' Populate CC with formula
                ws.Cells(i + 1, "CC").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Description ( Name as defined in Windchill )],MATCH([@[(Part Number)]],Table1[Part Number],0)),""Not in Part Master"")"
            Case "DELETE"
                ' Clear values
                ws.Cells(i + 1, "CB").ClearContents
                ws.Cells(i + 1, "CC").ClearContents
                ws.Cells(i + 1, "CD").ClearContents
        End Select
    Next i
    
    ' Re-enable screen updating and calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

I've also tried using the code below, but keep getting an out of memory error:
Sub UpdateColumnsBasedOnBR()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim chunkSize As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim brData As Variant
    Dim lData As Variant
    Dim mData As Variant
    Dim nData As Variant
    Dim cbData() As Variant
    Dim ccData() As Variant
    Dim cdData() As Variant
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM")
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column BR
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "BR").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set chunk size to process rows in smaller batches
    chunkSize = 1000
    
    ' Process data in chunks
    For startRow = 2 To lastRow Step chunkSize
        endRow = startRow + chunkSize - 1
        If endRow > lastRow Then endRow = lastRow
        
        ' Read relevant columns into arrays for faster processing
        brData = ws.Range("BR" & startRow & ":BR" & endRow).Value
        lData = ws.Range("L" & startRow & ":L" & endRow).Value
        mData = ws.Range("M" & startRow & ":M" & endRow).Value
        nData = ws.Range("N" & startRow & ":N" & endRow).Value
        
        ' Initialize output arrays
        ReDim cbData(1 To UBound(brData, 1), 1 To 1)
        ReDim ccData(1 To UBound(brData, 1), 1 To 1)
        ReDim cdData(1 To UBound(brData, 1), 1 To 1)
        
        ' Loop through the arrays and update values based on BR values
        For i = 1 To UBound(brData, 1)
            Select Case brData(i, 1)
                Case "SAME"
                    cbData(i, 1) = lData(i, 1)
                    ccData(i, 1) = mData(i, 1)
                    cdData(i, 1) = nData(i, 1)
                Case "REPLACE", "ADD"
                    ' Formulas will be handled separately
                    ccData(i, 1) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Description ( Name as defined in Windchill )],MATCH([@[(Part Number)]],Table1[Part Number],0)),""Not in Part Master"")"
                Case "DELETE"
                    cbData(i, 1) = vbNullString
                    ccData(i, 1) = vbNullString
                    cdData(i, 1) = vbNullString
            End Select
        Next i
        
        ' Write the updated arrays back to the worksheet
        ws.Range("CB" & startRow).Resize(UBound(cbData, 1), 1).Value = cbData
        ws.Range("CC" & startRow).Resize(UBound(ccData, 1), 1).Value = ccData
        ws.Range("CD" & startRow).Resize(UBound(cdData, 1), 1).Value = cdData
    Next startRow
    
    ' Handle the formula separately, as formulas cannot be directly written through arrays
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming row 1 is header
        If ws.Cells(i, "BR").Value = "REPLACE" Or ws.Cells(i, "BR").Value = "ADD" Then
            ws.Cells(i, "CC").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Description ( Name as defined in Windchill )],MATCH([@[(Part Number)]],Table1[Part Number],0)),""Not in Part Master"")"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


Cell-by-cell operations (writing, clearing) are slow.

formulas cannot be directly written through arrays - It's not right.  You can apply formulas on multiple cells with an array. eg: arrFormulaStr = Range("A1:A3").Formula : Range("C1:C3").Formula = arrFormulaStr. arrFormulaStr may be populated with other approach.

Copy Modified Values of Adjacent Columns Based on Corresponding Values in Another Column

Not tested!

Sub UpdateColumnsBasedOnBR()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "BOM"
    Const LKP_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "BR2"
    Const SRC_COLUMNS As String = "L:N"
    Const DST_FIRST_COLUMN As String = "CB"
    Const FORMULA_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const MY_FORMULA As String = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Description ( " _
        & "Name as defined in Windchill )],MATCH([@[(Part Number)]]," _
        & "Table1[Part Number],0)),""Not in Part Master"")"

    ' Reference the worksheet located in the workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    ' Return the values from the single-column lookup range
    ' in a 2D one-based (single-column) array, the lookup array.
    
    Dim lrg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(LKP_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data found!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set lrg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    If rCount = 1 Then ' one row (cell)
        ReDim lData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): lData(1, 1) = lrg.Value
    Else ' multiple rows (cells)
        lData = lrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Return the values from the source range
    ' in another 2D one-based array.
    
    ' The following simplifications assume:
    ' ... - at least 2 columns in 'SRC_COLUMN',...
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = lrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_COLUMNS).Value
    ' ... - at least as many columns as 'FORMULA_COLUMN'.
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    ' Modify the values in the array by applying the required logic
    ' using the corresponding values in the lookup array.
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        Select Case UCase(CStr(lData(r, 1)))
            Case "SAME" ' Carry over values
            Case "REPLACE", "ADD"
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    If c = FORMULA_COLUMN Then
                        Data(r, c) = MY_FORMULA
                    Else
                        Data(r, c) = Empty
                    End If
                Next c
            Case "DELETE"
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    Data(r, c) = Empty
                Next c
            Case Else ' maybe Case "SAME" should be this instead?
        End Select
    Next r
    
    ' Return the modified values of the array in the destination range.
    
    Dim drg As Range:
    Set drg = lrg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_FIRST_COLUMN).Resize(, cCount)
    drg.Value = Data
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Columns updated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

